# c-style array better container than std::array and std::vector for fixed size data that benifits from move semantics?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I am creating a new implementation of an N-dimensional vector (we'll call it `VectorND`) to replace some old code in a bigger system.
The vector size will be known at compile time, hence c-style arrays, `std::array` and `std::vector` are all viable candidates for the underlying data structure of the `VectorND` class.

I noticed that the vectors get passed around a lot, and think the system would benefit greatly if the new `VectorND` class could efficiently be moved. (I realize that a lot of the 'passing around' won't be able to use move's, but the vectors occur as rvalue's quite often too)

The `std::vector` class supports move semantics and as the c-style array is just a pointer both of these allow for trivial a move constructors/assignment operator in the `VectorND` class. The `std::array` class however needs O(n) time to be moved, which to me sounds like this "most obvious choice" is in fact the worst in this case.

For the remaining two, the c-style array can be allocated as a single chunk of memory and hence really use the fact that we know the size at compile time.

Am I missing something or **is the c-style array indeed the best underlying container for my `VectorND` class?**

(it sounds strange that the newer stl classes would be a worse choice)

**EDIT:** After reading through my post again, I realize that a `std::unique_ptr` to an `std::array` might give me the best of both worlds?

Comment: Moving the contents of an `std::array` is essentially the same as moving the contents of a C-style array

Comment: Possibly use one of the many matrix libraries out there?

Comment: A c-style array is not a pointer. You're probably thinking of a pointer to dynamically allocated memory. Which is what `std::vector` uses under the hood. Use the vector, unless you really want to save yourself the likely 8-byte overhead (needs keeping track of size and capacity, you only need size.)

Comment: @qxz Moving from `std::vector` is O(1).

Comment: "I realize that a std::unique_ptr to an std::array might give me the best of both worlds?" I don't think so. I'm not sure you understand what std::array is.

Comment: @qxz I wouldn't actually move the contents of the c-style array but only the pointer, however as juanchopanza pointed out, I'm probably mixing up some terminology here when I say "c-style array"

Comment: @NeilButterworth, In the case of the std_unique ptr, a move of the VectorND class would simply re-assign the pointer to the new VectorND, it would not touch the std::array

Comment: How big is "n"?  I've got a 4x4 homogenous matrix class in my ray tracer, but I figured the overhead of a call to the `new` operator to allocate memory from the heap so that I can just move the pointer in a move operation is worse than just using a normal array and copying the matrix's contents (although at 128 bytes per matrix, perhaps not...)

Comment: @Alnitak it differs for different parts of the system, but for the most its 80. I would however be interested if anyone knows of a rule-of-thumb on when (from what size?) these things become really significant? (with "these things" = being smart about moving vs copy-ing)

Comment: @NeilButterworth I think your statement is a bit harsh. In fact, a unique_ptr to an array combines moving in O(1), with size known at compile time, which can be an advantage.

Comment: `std::array` is simply a container that wraps a C array, and is essentially a C array with the generic container interface.

Comment: I think that the benefit of size known at compile time is only really a big advantage if the size is very small. For operations on primitives, you'll anyway have most of the processing done in some kind of clever partial loop unrolling that does 2 or 4 elements per go. `std::array` can be a very big win if the size is like, 3, or 5, because then you just unroll the entire loop. Even at size 80 the performance will be basically identical. And vector is a lot more ergonomic to work with; with `std::array` you either have to hardcode the size or make everything that touches it a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to follow juanchopanza's advice and go for the `std::vector`. As I already mentioned in the question it can be moved (in O(1)) and as juanchopanza pointed out, the overhead is very small.

Furthermore I like that it gives me the option to declare the move operations as default, increasing code readability. (I wanted to add a virtual destructor so I needed to add them as the compiler won't generate them when a destructor is specified)

For those interested, the relevant declarations:

```
/// Copy constructor
VectorND(const VectorND &) = default;
/// Move constructor
VectorND(VectorND &&) = default;
/// Copy assignment
VectorND& operator=(const VectorND &) = default;
/// Move assignment
VectorND& operator=(VectorND &&) = default;
/// Destructor
virtual ~VectorND() = default;
```